# Memory managed C++ singletons

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

I'm programming a game engine right now. The hardest part for me has been the memory management. I've been putting in as many optimizations as possible (because every frame counts, right?) and realized that the best way to approach this would be to do resource management using Stack and Pool allocators. The problem is, I can't figure out how to make a singleton class that is memory managed by these allocators.

My singletons are managers, so they are actually rather big, and memory management of them is important for the start up speed of my game. I basically want to be able to call my allocators' `alloc()` functions, which return type `void*`, and create my singleton in this allocated space.

I've been thinking about putting a `static boolean` called `instantiated` in each singleton class and having the constructor return `NULL` if `instantiated` is true. Would this work?

Comment: How many singletons do you need ? One, 5 of different classes, a lot of several classes, maybe you really want a "multiton"

Comment: Are you sure you need all the optimizations? Even if it's an engine, you should still do profiling first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is why everybody thinks Singletons suck. They suck horrifically. This is but one aspect of their suck, which will suck down your whole application with it.

In order to solve your problem: Do not use Suckletons.

Comment: Then what would you recommend as a suitable substitute? I want there to be only one instance of each manager. Should I just let my kernel initialize them and force users of the library to access them through the kernel?

Comment: @steelclaw: If you only want there to be one ... then only create one.

Comment: @steelclaw: If you don't want others to instantiate class A directly, make your "kernel" class a [friend class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friend_class) of A, and declare private all constructors of A. This way only a "kernel" object will be able to instantiate class A.

Comment: You could make the constructor private and have an accessor function that lazily initializes the sole instance and then stores it. Obviously threading may be an issue so be careful.

Comment: @DeadMG It's more complicated than that. One of the most important design elements of creating reusable, encapsulated code is that you don't want to subject the user to the inner workings of a library. There are important kernel variables that will be influenced by the various managers, so having two managers would be dangerous. Requiring the user to create one instance of a particular class and only one instance breaks the rules of encapsulation and is just plain bad design.

Comment: @steelclaw: More accurately, you have decomposed the kernel object beyond what is possible. Your "managers" are basically just individual parts of the kernel object. You should put all their interfaces together in one object. If the result is too much, then consider that your kernel does too much.

Comment: @everyone: I guess that from what you've been saying I should avoid singletons all together and either combine them with the kernel or else prevent them from modifying the kernel in ways that having more than one of a manager is dangerous. I think that the approach that I'll go with is to just have the managers allocated on my stack as normal objects, and pass pointers to them to the kernel. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I will answer this by sharing my own experience.  Normally I want a class to have all its own functionality and later realize ok this might need a factory method to supply other code with an instance of my object that  is singular.  The instance really should only be defined once to maintain state etc.  Therefore this is what I do for classes that don't have all of their initialization wrapped into construction.  I don't want to clutter my existing class with singletonsuxness so I create a factory wrapper class to help me with this.  You could use Myer's singleton pattern which is elegant and encapsulates the locking by letting the implementation of the static local variable (relies on compiler implementation of static local init which is not always a good idea) handle the locking but the problem comes if you, like me, want your objects default constructed so that you can use STL vectors etc on them easily and later call some type of initialization on them, possibly passing parameters to this method, to make them heavier.

```
class X
{
  public:


  bool isInitialized () { return _isInitialized; } ;  // or some method like 
                                                      // establishCxn to have it
                                                      // bootstrapped 
  void initialize();
  X() {} // constructor default, not initialized, light weight object

  private:
    bool _isInitialzied;

};

// set initialization to false 
X::X(): _isInitialized(false) {}

void X::intialize()
{
  if (isInitiazlied()) { return; }

   .... init code ....

  _isInitialized = true
}

// now we go ahead and put a factory wrapper on top of this to help manage the 
// singletoness nature.  This could be templatized but we don't as we want the 
// flexibility to override our own getinstance to call a specific initialize for the 
// object it is holding

class XFactory
{
public:

static X* getInstance();

private:
static boost::mutex _lock;

// light weight static object of yourself ( early instantiation ) to put on the stack 
// to avoid thread issues, static method member thread saftey, and DCLP pattern 
// threading races that can stem from compiling re-ordering of items

static XFactory _instance; 

// making this pointer volatile so that the compiler knows not to reorder our
// instructions for it ( depends on compiler implementation but it is a safe guard )
X* volatile _Xitem;  
X* getXitem () { return _Xitem; }

void createInstance();
void doCleanUp();

// stop instantiation or unwanted copies
XClientFactory();
~XClientFactory();
XClientFactory(XClientFactory const&);
XClientFactory& operator=(XClientFactory const&);

};

// on construction we create and set the pointer to a new light weight version of the 
// object we are interested in construction
XFactory::XFactory() : _Xitem( new X; )
{
}

// note our factory method is returning a pointer to X not itself (XFactory)
X* XFactory::getInstance()
{
// DCLP pattern, first thread might have initialized X while others
// were waiting for the lock in this way your double check locking is 
// on initializing the X container in the factory and not the factory object itself.  
// Worst case your initialization could happen more than once but it should check the 
// boolean before it starts (see initialization method above) and sets the boolean at 
// the end of it. Also your init should be such that a re-initialization will not put 
// the object in a bad state.  The most important thing to note is that we
// moved the double check locking to the contained object's initialization method
// instead of the factory object

  if (! XFactory::_instance.getXitem()->isInitialized() )
  {
    boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> guard(XFactory::_lock);
    if (! XFactory::_instance.getXitem()->isInitialized() )
    {
      XFactory::_instance.getXitem()->initialize();
    }
  }
  return XFactory::_instance.getXitem();
}


// XFactory private static instance on the stack will get cleaned up and we need to 
// call the delete on the pointer we created for the _Xitem

XFactory::~XFactory()
{
  doCleanUp();
}
XFactory::doCleanUp()
{
  delete _Xitem; // 
}
```

That's it, let me know what you think.  I also wrestled recently with singleton and all the pit falls.  Also, we are not using a 0x compiler yet that would ensure that the Myers singleton will be implemented in a thread safe way just using a local static variable